# PHP - Before Searching the DB for a Match how to clean out the Common text and Characters?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am currently doing search functionality for search for a string in multiple columns and multiple tables want to know how the best way to pre-process the search text before doing the database search

for example search text may be

```
"Sales / Marketing Executives - Full/Part time - 20% Commission"
```

Ideally i want to remove "/", "-", "%" ...etc before searching

because even i use the MySQL query as

```
LIKE '% KEYWORD %'
```

Still a common search like

```
"Sales Executives"
```

won't match above string, Remember i am NOT looking for a just simple

```
STR_REPLACE solution
```

because it will be impossible to cleanup all the possible search alternatives in this way,

any other ideas ?

Comment: Just use a fulltext search. It'll handle ignoring "non-text" and too-frequent words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html. `LIKE` is pretty much useless for the type of search you want, and fulltext is designed for it.

Comment: hwo do i combine fulltext search with common AND operators like (
    1 AND e.status='active' AND ( j.status='published' OR j.status='expired' )
   )

Comment: @mahen3d I'd suggest you start by reading the documentation that MarcB linked

Comment: i did there are many rescrictions on this full text search, ie. Full-text searches are supported for MyISAM tables only. AND there is no way to combine more than one AND operator .. which makes useless for me to use it..

Comment: fulltext is supported on innodb as of 5.5(? going off memory) somewhere.